# GMaps API: Search Map via Lat/LonCoordinates and Addresses

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been using the Geocoder service in the Google Maps API to power a search box on my map. I wish to allow users to search freely by address, city and coordinates and perhaps anything else that is supported. Until recently if I passed latitude/longitude coordinates to the geocoder it would simply return me a result of those specific coordinates but lately it has changed to do a reverse lookup and provide me the nearest address to the coordinates. I actually want the location directly at the coordinates as that is what is most relevant.

Any ideas how to either parse out the various input forms of coordinates from the search box or get the geocoder to revert to its earlier behaviour?

Comment: Can you post some code demonstrating what you are doing?

Comment: Here's the jist of what I'm doing currently: [code paste](http://pastebin.com/LhwkpceK)

Comment: So to clarify your question, what you are explaining is that if you enter a lat/lng pair into the input you have created with the id of "txt_googlesearch" you are expecting the map to center on that specific location? And that it used to do so through the geocoder, but is now doing a reverse lookup?

Comment: Right. If I passed a location of <coordinates> to the address of the geocoder it returned a location of <coordinates>. Now if I do the same it does a reverse geocode and returns a location of <nearest address> instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it would have changed to showing reverse geocoding, without seeing the code. However, I would suggest using the [Autocomplete feature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete) of the Places API Library instead.

Comment: Places doesn't handle coordinates at all from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use a regex to check if the input entered is a lat/lng pair? And then if it is parse that pair and navigate to the coordinates directly. Something like:

```
  var latLngRegex =   /^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$/; //Regex for checking that it is a latlng pair that has been entered

  var address = document.getElementById("txt_googlesearch").value;
  if (address=='' || address=='Search') {
    return;
  }
  if (latLngRegex.test(address)) //Run the regex against the entered value
  {
    var coords = address.split(","); //Split the address into 2 decimal values
    var mapPoint = new GLatLng(parseInt(coords[0]), parseInt(coords[1]));  //Create a gLatLng from the split values
    map.setCenter(mapPoint); //Move the map to the entered location
    return;
  } 
  //Call Geocoder as before
```

Comment: Yes, that is certainly one option, but there are quite a few different coordinate formats that would need to be parsed.